# Force browser to load last angularjs app code

Tags: html, angularjs, browser-cache

I have a web application in production environment because of cache clients does not always have the newest version of our code

How can I solve this problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a version param to the url of your scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-script.js?v=1.0.1"></script>
```

This way, you can control manually wich one of your script needs to be reloaded. You shouldn't have to change anything to your file name.

Comment: it's not working :( i need to refresh my browser to get new lastest updates

Comment: just make sure that every time you update the script, you update the versionning too. If you dont care about cache at all, you can put the current date instead of the version number.

Comment: How can this work if the index is cached also? For us it doesn't. How about adding `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />`? Can you explain the behavior?

Comment: Well, if the file `my-script.js?v=1.0.1` is cached, you must change the version itself in order to refresh it. That way, users benefit form the cache, and it's simple for devs to force a refresh when an update is done.